# Can I use OpenCV to analyze a video for how long a face is in the centre of the screen?

Tags: opencv, virtual-reality, htc-vive

This is a frame from a video taken using the HTC Vive (it's from the user's perspective of a game I developed in Unity) I've overlaid those boxes in paint.

I'm trying to determine which character the person is looking at (assuming the white box is where they user is focusing)

I know this can be done in Unity without the need for a video, but I want to know if the video can be analyzed using something like OpenCV to detect how long each character faces is in the white box. I just made this in paint to get the idea across, the parameters aren't to scale or anything, I just have no idea where to start with a concept like this apart from OpenCV.

But to summarize, can I use OpenCV to detect how long each face is in the centre of the screen? i.e. How long the user looked at each character.

[image: **Thought Experiment**]

Comment: I don't see why not. If you have the coordinates of the bounding box you can determine if it's in the center. If you do so by frame you should be able to determine the time as well.

Comment: Okay it sounds promising. And it's possible to fix those bounding boxes to follow the faces of each character?

Comment: It's doing it frame by frame, so this should not be any problem. There are a lot of live demos if you search for them.